# What makes a popular and insightful question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

One of the things that will probably continue to grow our site are popular questions that get many views that contribute to a valuable conversation.

Questions range from topics such as [monetary policy](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/what-does-yanis-varoufakis-mean-by-surplus-recycling-mechanism) to [obesity policies](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9388/economic-policies-to-decrease-obesity-would-they-be-effective). Technical mathematical questions, while valuable, don't tend to get the attention that practical policy questions get. The difference in attention is really quite notable. How do you think people come to find questions they are interested in, and how should that inform the type of content we should encourage on this site?

Answer (score 2):

I enjoy (some) practical questions. However the SE format is more or less for clear answers. Practical questions often do not have those. For example leading economists disagree on the medium term effects of austerity policies. If we do not wish to fall back to referencing authority as an argument, real answers have to contain some technical information about the model.

I would also argue that attracting visitors is not really our job. There are also some practical questions that would no doubt attract a large number of visitors but the same can be said of the 'news' items of Buzzfeed. The survival of Economics.SE should not be paramount to what the content of Economics.SE is.

Comment: Also read: 10 Ways To Get More Upvotes On Your Question

Comment: Also read: The Economics of Keeping Up With The Kardashians

Comment: well u certainly got my upvote! :^OO

Comment: I agree with this answer.